# Fetch the first row of each group by active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What I want:

```
    select * from messages where id in (select max(id) from messages where from_user_id=1 or to_user_id=1 group by from_user_id,to_user_id);
```

when I do a query by active record

```
msg_ids = Message.where("from_user_id=? or to_user_id=?",1,1).group(:from_user_id,:to_user_id).select("max(id)")
```

the mysql output is;

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM `messages` WHERE (from_user_id=1 or to_user_id=1)  GROUP BY `messages`.`from_user_id` LIMIT 11
```

Why limit 11? How can i iterate the msg_ids?

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very awkward to use active record to do complicated work.
use find_by_sql will simply the work very much.

```
    sql = "select * from messages where id in (select max(id) from messages where from_user_id=#{self.id} or to_user_id=#{self.id} group by from_user_id,to_user_id)"
    Message.find_by_sql(sql)
```

but still not understand why limit 11?
the limit 11 problem u can refer to
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30497